# Access Unavailable This resource is only for developers enrolled in a developer program

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-developer

I have to create a APN Certificate to enable Firebase push notification 
But when I goes to create APN Certificate, it's shows Like the attached Image. What are the steps I have to do? Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: You need to have an active and paid Apple Developer License to create certificates

Comment: are you by any chance using Internet Explorer? try with  Safari or Chrome.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although i have enrolled account but happened to me too. i emailed to apple support system.they asked me for providing some document that proves my address in my apple id profile.